# Using the same OrderByAttribute for two attributes in one dimension

Tags: sorting, ssas

In my SSAS cube I have a dimension with attributes A and B, and I want both to be displayed in the sort order specified by a third attribute C. If I specify C as the OrderByAttribute for A and reprocess the cube, then A is sorted correctly.

If I then specify C as the OrderByAttribute for B as well and reprocess the cube, then A continues to be sorted correctly but B does not. Values of B are displayed in an order that seems arbitrary. I have triple-checked that there is no difference in the way A and B are configured.

Is there some conceptual reason why two attributes in a single dimension cannot be both sorted by the same third attribute?

Comment: Which version of AS are you using? To have an attribute being the sort attribute of another, there must be a relationship from the attribute to be sorted to the sort attribute. Have you these set up? Is there exactly one sort attribute member per attribute member of both attributes to be sorted?

Comment: Using Analysis Services 10.50.1600.1.

Comment: In the dsv, I have a table called "cm" which contains the two attributes to be sorted (I called them A and B in the main description). There is a separate table called "DisplayOrder" that simply contains a list of the possible members of A and B, along with a numeric value that puts those into the order I want. There is a relationship between A and the key column of DisplayOrder and an identical relationship between B and the key column of DisplayOrder.

Comment: In the dimension, I have the field A, B, and the numeric sort value from the DisplayOrder table. There is an attribute relation from the dimension's primary key to A, and from A to the sort value. There is a similar line of relationships from primary key to B to the sort value. There is a 1-1 rel between values of A/B and the sort value.

Comment: In the Attributes Relationships diagram, SSAS warned about having two input to the sort value. In first case I ignored that warning and processed the cube anyway. In a second case, I created two hierarchies (one with the two levels sort order and A, and the second with two levels sort order and B), which made the warning go away, and re-processed. In both cases, A is sorted correctly, but not B.

Comment: I am not sure this is intended behavior, maybe it is a bug that you should report at http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer. Nevertheless, as a workaround, maybe it would help to duplicate the sort attribute: Just rename the existing attribute maybe to sortA, and drag the attribute from the table in the right to the attribute list in the left another time, renaming the new attribute to sortB. Then adapt the relationships and sort settings such that A relates to sortA, and is sorted by it, and B is related ty and sorted by sortB.

Comment: That is an insightful idea @FrankPl, but it did not make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now located the problem but still looking for a solution.

As mentioned in the comments, the dsv has tables CM and DisplayOrder between which there are two relationships -- from CM.A to DisplayOrder.primarykey and from CM.B to DisplayOrder.primarykey. SSAS constructs the attribute A using the query:

```
select distinct CM.A, DisplayOrder.SortOrder
from
    (<named query for CM>) as CM,
    (<named query for DisplayOrder>) as DisplayOrder
where CM.A = DisplayOrder.primarykey
```

That is correct and works fine. But when SSAS constructs the attribute B, it uses the query:

```
select distinct CM.B, DisplayOrder.SortOrder
from
    (<named query for CM>) as CM,
    (<named query for DisplayOrder>) as DisplayOrder
where CM.A = DisplayOrder.primarykey
```

Note that the `where` clause links the two tables using A rather than for B.

So in summary, when the dsv has two tables with two relationships between them, the join in the queries generated by SSAS to implement the OrderByAttribute always use one of those relationships and ignores the other.

Any idea why, or if there is a property somewhere I may have missed?

Comment: Some suggestions: if you use named queries anyway, you could as well include the display order column in the named query for CM. And if the problem persists, just add the same expression twice so you have two columns in the named query.

Comment: I am not convinced the DSV is the culprit: I woudl assume taht even if you remove the relationships in the DSV, the behavior would be the same. As far as I am aware, the relationships in the DSV are just used in the wizards of BIDS to help generate things, but are not actually used by any other code. Nevertheless, even if they had absolutely no functionality, they would still be useful for display purposes. I would assume the main culprit for the wrong behavior being the relationships between attributes. Maybe you have a relationship from B to A defined?

Comment: Your first comment is quite right @FrankPl. I've now done a similar thing: duplicated the DisplayOrder named query.